Parabolas to the right or to the left
I would like some help to make the opening (concavity) of the parabolas go to the right or left, and not up or down.
Manipulate[
 Plot[a  (y - k)^2 + h, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Parabola: x = " <> ToString[a] <> "(y - " <> ToString[k] <> 
    ")^2 + " <> ToString[h], GridLines -> Automatic, 
  ImageSize -> Large], {{a, 1, "Aperture"}, -5, 5, 
  0.1}, {{h, 0, "Vertex x"}, -10, 10, 0.1}, {{k, 0, "Vertex y"}, -10, 
  10, 0.1}]


Solve for y in terms of x and then plot y.  You will have to separately plot both branches since y will no longer be single valued.  When you plot x vs y M will take x as the vertical axis, regardless what you label it.

Have you tried something like this ParametricPlot[{x^2,x},{x,-1,1}]?

Based on the posted comments, I made the following changes:
Manipulate[(*Define the quadratic function*)f[y_] := a  y^2 + b  y + c;
 (*Plot the quadratic function*)
 ParametricPlot[{f[y], y}, {y, -10, 10}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   "Graph of the Parabola x = " <> ToString[a] <> "y^2 + " <> 
    ToString[b] <> "y + " <> ToString[c], AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-10, 10}}], {{a, 1}, -5, 5}, {{b, 0}, -10,
   10}, {{c, 0}, -10, 10}]


Just a tip or style thing:
For functions like yours with parameters, I like to define them like this:
f[a_,b_,c_][y_] := a  y^2 + b  y + c
Definitions like this are pretty flexible and you can pass them to other functions that take functions as arguments.

I'm trying to take your question at face value:

why the openings of the parabolas are not to the right or to the left

To explain, let's look at the core of your Plot:
Plot[a (y - k)^2 + h, {y, -10, 10}]

The symbols a, k, and h are parameters that change some characteristics of the parabola's shape, but none of them change the orientation with regard to the axes. So, we can just focus on:
Plot[y^2, {y, -10, 10}]

The independent variable is y and standard practice is to map the independent variable to the horizontal axis. The fact that the name of this variable is y and that countless high school math teachers have taught us to associate y with the vertical axis doesn't matter. The symbol y is purely a formal symbol. We could have used anything:
Plot[anything^2, {anything, -10, 10}]

So, the reason why the parabola's axis of symmetry is vertical rather than horizontal is just a consequence of how you've chosen to model the parabola along with the fact that the independent variable is automatically mapped to the horizontal axis.

I've rephrased my question to be more specific about my interest. My goal is to obtain parabolas with concavity to the right or left by varying the parameters a, b, and c.
